# Interpretation of time dilation

Tags: photons, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

Is there any interpretiation of time dilation for photons? I mean, how does time work for them? Do photons have any distinction between their own and observer's time? Or is it something like ultimate time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure how much relativity you know, but usually we write the 'Proper time' for a particle moving through the x direction and time as 
$$
(c \Delta \tau)^2 = (c \Delta t)^2 - (\Delta x)^2
$$
Where proper time $\tau$ is just the time that the particle would measure in it's own internal frame. So if you are travelling fast on a rocket ship, someone else says you've been travelling $\Delta t$ seconds whereas you would look at your own watch and say 'no, I've been gone $\Delta \tau$ seconds!' since from your point of view you never moved, the earth just rocketed away from you while you stayed still.

If you look at this equation, it looks a lot like the Pythagorean identity except it's got a negative sign in there. What it tells you is that an object moving really fast through space moves slower through time, and the difference between these two things squared is how much time passed from the moving particle's point of view.

What about photons? We know for a fact that photons travel at speed $v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=c$ (photons travel this fast from **everybody's** point of view, no matter how fast you are travelling. The speed of light is a true universal constant, unlike elapsed time). If we plug this into our equation above to find the proper time experienced by a photon, we can use $\Delta x=c \Delta t$, which implies that 
$$
(c\Delta \tau)^2=(c\Delta t)^2-(c\Delta t)^2 = 0
$$
So, that means that if you travel at the speed of light , you observe no time passing (this is why massive objects like humans cannot travel at the speed of light)! This means that photons don't experience time at all. From their point of view, they reach their end point at the exact moment they are emitted. It makes no sense to talk. About a time dilation for a photon.

This is a central result in special relativity and it should help your intuition if you pursue more knowledge in the field.

**Edit:** Some people have (rightly) jumped on me for being loose with my language. I made a statement regarding travelling at c, which I should have emphasized is impossible. I should have also emphasized that no matter what speed you travel at light always travels at c (which is obvious from the proper time equation I used above).

However, I believe that the criticism claiming that I am wrong is uncharitable. Asking 'what if I travel at speed c?' and then looking at the space time interval and its consequences for your proper time should be a step towards convincing oneself that one cannot travel at c if they wish to experience proper time as all massive observers must.

There is in fact a reference frame at c (the null reference frame), it just isn't very interesting since it's null and it's inaccessible to a massive observer.

Comment: There is no inertial reference frame with speed $c$ in any other inertial reference frame.  Put another way, an entity with speed $c$ in an inertial reference frame has speed $c$ in all inertial reference frames.  Thus, "if you travel at the speed of light", you have no inertial reference frame with which to make observations.  So, it makes no sense to claim "you observe no time passing!"

Comment: While you have manipulated the math in one way, you have missed the central tenet of relativity that the speed of light is the same in all frames, meaning the manipulation is not physically reasonable.

Comment: Hi Mason. I think Alfred and Jon are being a bit unkind, because most of your answer is just fine and you correctly pull out the key point that the proper time along a photon trajectory is always zero (this is true in general relativity as well). However I agree that the sentence *So, that means that if you travel at the speed of light, you observe no time passing!* is meaningless and you should edit it out.

Comment: Hi all, I have edited my post, if you still disagree with what I've written we can discuss it further.